# Next.js - yarn dev: error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV"

Tags: npm, next.js, yarnpkg, package.json

I am having this problem, whenever I am running `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
warning ../../../../package.json: No license field
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /
wait  - compiling...
error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^10.2.3",
    "react": "17.x",
    "react-dom": "17.x",
    "webpack": "^5.39.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Certainly, this information is not sufficient to know what went wrong. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, can you verify if this issue is not the same as your problem: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/24421

Comment: If you are using a mac with M1, the problem can be fixed using node version -> v16.5.0 or above on Mac M1.
just use: `nvm install v16.5.0` if you are using nvm...

Comment: I'm having this issue trying to run on ARM64 docker with `node:current-alpine` (which is node `17.4.0` ... still looking for a solution

Answer (score 4):

Appears to be a problem with **Mac M1**, as [@Fernando Gomes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062292/fernando-gomes) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019023/next-js-yarn-dev-error-command-failed-with-signal-sigsegv#comment123147676_68019023).

In order to get it working on my environment, I am using *Docker* with following parameters:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 .
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this first do a clean:

```bash
yarn clean
```

Then

```
yarn dev
```

Comment: Thank-you for this simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a problem with the Wifi :?. I know is weird by switching off wifi and everything start working.